# Getting selected Item of WKInterfacePicker

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I am trying to use a `WKInterfacePicker` to select a string from a list. As of now, I am using an `IBAction` function and am updating a variable that stores the value for the picker. The variable, however, does not get updated if I spin the digital crown too quickly, even though the selected element in the picker differs from the value of the variable. Additionally, the selected element when the view is first loaded, sometimes differs from the initial value of the variable (e.g. 0 is selected in the picker, but the value of the variable is 2). I believe that my `IBOutlets` and `IBActions` are wired up correctly in IB. Is this a bug in the beta software, or am I using the `WKInterfacePicker` incorrectly? Here is the code for the `WKInterfaceController`:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
    @IBOutlet var itemPicker:WKInterfacePicker?
    var pickerVal = 0

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)       

        var itemArr = [WKPickerItem]()

        for n in 0...5 {
            let k = WKPickerItem()
            k.title = String(n)
            itemArr.append(k)
        }



        itemPicker?.setItems(itemArr)

        itemPicker?.setEnabled(false)
    }

    override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
        itemPicker?.setSelectedItemIndex(0)

        itemPicker?.setEnabled(true)
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

    @IBAction func itemPickerUpdated(index: Int) {
        pickerVal = index
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that it's a WatchOS 2 beta 1 bug. I can reproduce the same problem, and many other people reported the same.

Hopefully there will be a fix on the next beta.

Update: Still broken in beta 2

Update: Can't even run app in beta 3

Update: ... or beta 4

Update: Can't build using El Capitan beta 6 + XCode 7 beta 4

Comment: Getting the same behavior in beta2. Good to know it is not only me :)

Comment: This bug is fixed in WatchOS beta 5.